# Converting to a [string, string][] datatype

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having a model class which consists a [string,string][] datatype. I am inserting a value into that array. But when I JSON.stringify the array, my array is enclosed within an additional array.

```
const myArray: [string, string][] = [];

..forEach(modelItem => { 
const arrayItem: [string, string] = ['modelItem.attribute1', 'modelItem.attribute2'];
myArray.push(arrayItem);
});

console.log('JSON.stringify(myArray): ' + JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

And the result of this log is :

```
JSON.stringify(myArray): [["modelItem.attribute1", "modelItem.attribute2"]]. (a double square bracket)
```

My target is to achieve the below result:

```
JSON.stringify(myArray): ["modelItem.attribute1", "modelItem.attribute2"] (notice the single square bracket).
```

I am just not sure how to get this structure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray: [string, string][] = [];
```

You already declared a multi dimensional array . try to remove the `[]` besides `[string,string]`

Comment: I will have to assign this array to an attribute with the same [string, string][] type. If I remove the [], Type '[string, string]' is not assignable to type '[string, string][]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '[string, string]'

Comment: you can map your two dimensional array whenever you want to use it as a single dimensional array with map function then stringify it

Comment: @HDM91, `BAGArgsData.BAGContexts = this.getMyArray();` The datatype of reviewContexts is [string,string][]. If I remove the [] besides, there is a type conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring like this:

```
const myArray: [string, string][] = [];
```

Means it'll be *an array* **of arrays of strings**. So just declare it as an array of two strings, removing the additional `[]` which means "an array of whatever is before this":

```
const myArray: [string, string] = [];
```

Comment: `BAGArgsData.BAGContexts = this.getMyArray();` The datatype of reviewContexts is [string,string][]. If I remove the [] besides, there is a type conversion error.